# Difference between Färe-Primont index and Lowe index

Tags: r, performance

In the 'productivity' package on R there is a Färe-Primont and a Lowe index given. As I understood this are different measures to calculate aggregate input and aggregate output funktions.

But I cannot find the exact difference between them. Can you recommend me any literature to read or summarize the difference briefly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'Lowe indexes are constructed by choosing linear weighting functions and by 
choosing prices as measures of value, Färe-Primont indexes are constructed using non-linear 
weighting functions and normalized shadow (or support) prices14 as measures of value, and 
Geometric Young indexes are constructed using log-linear weighting functions and income 
and cost shares as measures of value.'

http://www.uq.edu.au/economics/cepa/docs/WP/WP072011.pdf
Page 14